# Angular, Http post return object

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, http, post

I have this function that finds an object to my database and should return it, I put a conse.log before to see if there it is the object I want to get and works correctly.

Here it is my service:

```
buscarUsuario(email: string){

 return this.http.post(`${URL}/user/email`, email)
          .subscribe(resp => {      
          //Here i can see the object and works      
          console.log(resp['usuario']);
          
          //This return doesn't work
          return resp['usuario'];
          
         });
```

}

And here it is the function of my backend, this one I tested it in Postman and works correctly:

```
userRoutes.post('/email', async(req: Request, res: Response) => {

const usuario = await Usuario.findOne({email: req.body.email});

res.json({
    ok: true,
    usuario
});
```

});

So, can anyone tell me how to return that object? Please :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return value from `.subscribe()` method. `.subscribe()` returns `Subscription` to appropriate `Observable`. The question is what you want to achieve?

Comment: So, how do I return that object?

Comment: All depend on what you want to do with this object. `Observable` concept bases on reactivity. So you can create stream
`buscarUsuario(email: string){

 return this.http.post(`${URL}/user/email`, email)
}

stream$ = buscarUsario("email@email.com")`

This stream you can use in your template with `async` pipe

Alternatively, you can call `await this.http.post(`${URL}/user/email`, email).toPromise()` and grab value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are returning a function. A better approach to return the object is to use something like a promise.

For example

```
function buscarUsuario(email: string){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.http.post(`${URL}/user/email`, email)
             .subscribe(resp => {      
             //Here i can see the object and works      
             console.log(resp['usuario']);
             
             resolve(resp['usuario'])
            }); 
  })
```

now you can access the object in 1 of 2 ways either by calling `.then()` or using `async await`

first method

```
...
buscarUsuario(...)
   .then(usuario => {
         // usuario is your object
   })
   .catch(err => { throw err })
```

a cleaner way would be using `async` `await`

```
let usuario = await buscarUsuario(...)
```

keep in mind for the 2nd way your function which includes that line must be `async`

for example

```
async function test() {
    let usuario = await buscarUsuario(...)
}
```

**EDIT**

```
function buscarUsuario(email: string){
    return this.http.post(`${URL}/user/email`, email).toPromise()
}
```

or

```
function buscarUsuario(email: string){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.http.post(`${URL}/user/email`, email)
             .toPromise()
             .then(resp => {      
             //Here i can see the object and works      
             console.log(resp['usuario']);
             
             resolve(resp['usuario'])
            }); 
  })
```

The main difference is the 2nd method will return the value instead of the object

```
async function test() {
    let usuario = await buscarUsuario(...)
}
```

Something like this should work. Try it and let me know the results

Comment: I tried right now the second way, the async function, and now returns me a null object, at the console.log says null too

Comment: did you wrap `this.http.post` with a `promise` like I did?

Comment: I checked my answer I forgot to add quotation here `resolve(resp[usuario])` it should be `resolve(resp['usuario'])`

Comment: Yes, I figured it out before, I tried and stills saying null.

Comment: Okay try `return this.http.post("${URL}/user/email", email).toPromise())` make sure to use ` instead of "

Comment: I still get null D:.

Comment: That is unfortunate, you tried both methods under `Edit` and they both resulted in null?

Comment: Yes, at least now returns me an object, not what I want but at least something. Thank you so much for your help, I'll try to do something else.

Comment: The first method is intended to return an object but the 2nd method should work 100% fine.

Comment: I'll test more with the second then

Comment: Okey, the way you showed me works, the problem i had it's that I put the param in a wrong way in the method this.http.post(`${URL}/user/email`, email), now i put it in {} and works this.http.post(`${URL}/user/email`, {email}). Thank you so much for the help, and sorry for the loss of time

Comment: I am glad it worked for you! and no worries no need to apologies. Please consider marking the question if it helped you and also checking @code-gorilla's answer as it is pretty accurate as well. Good luck with the rest.

Answer (score 0):

The right way would be to not subscribe in the service method, but to return the observable:

```
buscarUsuario(email: string){
  return this.http.post(`${URL}/user/email`, email)
          .pipe(map(resp => resp['usuario']))        
});
```

Then you can subscribe to the method, from any other place, e.g. your component:

```
componentMethod() {
  this.myService.buscarUsuario.subscribe(usuario => this.usuario = usuario);
}
```